# what is K-completeness? (Kelly completeness)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, complete-spaces, domain-theory

I'm studing Domain theory and working on maximal point space problem. I couldn't find any book or sci-text about K-completness and D-completness!Can any body give me some help with this?

Comment: $D$ sounds like "directed -complete" every directed set has a supremum. Maybe the other notion is just that all suprema and infima exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the references in the Wikipedia page on [domain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory).

As an example, there is the following [PDF file](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/handy1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks but i studed those, There wasn't any difinition of K-completeness!